# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on External Hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I wish to install to my 160 gb external hard disk, but it has already got four partitions. This is how my partitions are listed when I use the live CD

```
/dev/sdb
  /dev/sdb1  -- 100 mb (System Reserved partition)
  /dev/sdb2 -- 58 gb (this is where I want to install the ubuntu )
  /dev/sdb3 --40 gb (contains some data)
  /dev/sdb4 --40 gb (contains some data)
```

So when I tried to split up the  58 gb partition in this pattern 56 gb (for ubuntu) and 2gb for the swap sapce. The 2 gb is now turned into **unusable space** instead of **free space** and I had done some google search on that, it said that only 4 partitions could be created including the primary and the logical. So how should I proceed here inorder to install ubuntu to my external hard disk? could someone please help me with this ?

Thanks,
Varun Krishna. P

Comment: Since it seems you want to keep the other 3 partitions, you can install ubuntu in only one partition without swap. You can use a swap file instead - which should let you do everything in one partition. You should have hibernate/suspend that will not work...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use one of the 40gb partition to create a swap partition. Try to transfer the data from the partition you will use for swap to another that won't be changed. Then, with a partition app, try to merge the two partitions (58 and 40gb). After, split it in one swap partition and one ext4. Finally, install Linux in the ext4 partition.

Good luck friend. Hope it helps.

Comment: Kako, What if I remove the partition sdb1 that 100 mb ? will I be able to split the sdb2 ? and how do I remove that unusable 2 gb partition ?

Comment: If both partitions are adjacents and are secondary, its fine. You can merge them and then split. The unusable 2gb will be merged with the others when you erase them.

Comment: I have removed the partition sdb1 and sdb2 and merged both of them, during the installation I divided them accordingly,now it is working fine.